# Use singleton EJBs in Eclipse Projects

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, singleton, ejb

I just downloaded some days ago the last versions of Eclipse and JBoss, created a SessionBean (EJB3.x) project and now I'm trying to create an Singleton EJB, but eclipse is not allowing me to do it and gives me the folowing warning message " The 'Singleton' state type is allowed only for EJB projects with version 3.1 or later". Unhappily, when I create the project, the hihgst version possible is 3.0.

What am I doing wrong? I need a singleton Ejb now!!!

Thanks in advance,
Saul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

Indeed Jboss 5.1 didn't support EJB 3.1, but JBoss 6.0 does!

Just an observation to those are facing this same problem. Eclipse doesn't have the adapter for JBoss 6.0, but if you use the one provided for JBoss 5.0 it works just fine (I read somewhere there might be some problems, but at least till now, it's ok).

Also, if you try to create an singleton EJB through Eclipse, it'll not work, but you can create another type of EJB and then change the annotation to @Singleton and it'll work.

Best Regards,
Saul